# How to use a Structure member to dynamically allocate a member array?

Tags: c, arduino

Here's what I want to do:

```
//Define a structure to store multistep sequences.
struct Command 
{
  int Steps; //Number of steps in the seq
  int StepCount; //must be set to -1
  int Seq[Steps][NUMSERVOS + 1];
};
```

For example, a `Command` initialization could look like this:

```
Command Home = {1,-1,{90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 1000}};
```

This line would then result in the int `Array Seq` having the size `[7][1]` (`NUMSERVOS == 6`)

I want the `Array Seq[][]` to initialize with the value held in `Steps`.

The problem is that:

1. `Steps` is not a constant integer.
2. `Steps` is not static.

Is there anyway I can dynamically allocate memory to the array using members initialized before the array?

Comment: Is this definitely C++?  If I recall correctly, usually Arduino work is C.

Comment: My mistake, Arduino is based off C not C++

Answer (score 3):

Arduino is a tiny, resource-limited platform. Using dynamic allocation in embedded systems in general is a bad idea, and using it on a little 8-bitter is a very bad idea. There are far too many problems with dynamic memory: it requires a heap, which is a luxury 8-bitters can't afford, it gives you problems with fragmentation and memory leaks, and it is very very slow.

What you should do is to analyse the input of the program and determine the worst-case scenario, then allocate sufficient memory statically to cover the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:** That was originally posted with a C++ tag. The template solution can not work with plain old C.

You can consider using a template this way:

```
//Define a structure to store multistep sequences.
template<int n>
struct Command 
{
    // n = Number of steps in the seq
    int StepCount; //must be set to -1
    int Seq[n][NUMSERVOS + 1];
};
```

I'll assume you want this value to be useful just when you create the command since you're trying to use a static array. Then you'll be able to instantiate your structure this way:

```
Command<1> Home = {-1, {90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 1000}};
```

Now, if you still want to get Steps from there, you can still create a getter that way in your structure:

```
int Steps() const
{
    return n;
}
```

**C solution**

Actually, if you compile your code just the way you gave it with a C99 or C11 compiler, it may work thanks to variable length arrays support. I can't ensure VLAs are accepted in structures though.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use Command.Steps because it will always be defined. My thinking is why pass another value when I already have it stored in Steps? My program has to know how many entries there are in the sequence so Steps does need to be useful outside of the init

Comment: It depends on what you want to do right after. From what I can see, the value of Steps won't change after instantiation. If you want to get Steps, you can still create a getter, say :
    int Steps() const { return n; }

Comment: would int Steps() be a member of the structure?

Comment: Yes, it would. But it wouldn't weight anything in your structure.

Comment: By the way, I did not know Arduino. Anyway, this solution won't work if you use plain old C.

Comment: So the structure would look like this template<int n> struct Command { int StepCount; int Seq[n][NUMSERVOS +1; int Steps() const {return n;} };

Comment: You forgot to close the bracket after NUMSERVOS+1, but yeah, it would look like that.

Comment: You will probably want to avoid most of C++, as well as VLAs, on a tiny 8-bitter.

Comment: Mmmh, you're right. At first, I just considered the problem syntaxically. I should have had a look a what Arduino was before.